# How to get the Grantor of a granted role to a user?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to get the Grantor of a granted role to a user in Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this information is not stored in the data dictionary.

It is only possible to find the GRANTOR of **priviledges** granted to users on **objects** (Tables columns, etc). This info is in the tables `dba_tab_privs`, `dba_col_privs`, etc...

A ROLE can be granted to a user, by anyone having either :

- GRANT ANY ROLE system privilege
- ADMIN OPTION (all DBAs, in others)
- or being the OWNER of the ROLE

The only way to get this information would be to activate the audit trail for DBAs (`audit_sys_operations=true`) and GRANT ROLE operations (`SQL> audit grant any role by access;`), and to search the audit logs.